Standard Deviation of a Normal Distribution
I am trying to understand what standard deviation actually is in the context of a normal distribution. Previously for a set of numbers, the standard deviation has been the mean of the squared distances from the mean. I understand this.
However, in the context of distribution it doesn't make much sense to me. We don't really know specific values in a normal distribution so what is the standard deviation actually telling us. Furthermore, consider the standardised normal distribution. It has a standard deviation of 1. So why can we calculate probabilities like $P(Z<1.35)$, if the standard deviation is only 1. Standard deviation doesn't make much sense to me in this context. What's the point of standardising the standard deviation to 1?

Every normal-distribution can be transformed into the standard-normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard derivation $1$. If E is the expectation and S the standard deviation of $X$ , we just need to consider $Y=\frac{X-E}{S}$. The adavantage is that we can work with tables and easily compute probabilities.

It is not clear whether you are confused by the purpose of the standard deviation in general or by the standardisation of the normal distribution in the end.

I don't understand.  for a probability density $p(x)$ with mean $\mu$  you can define variance as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-\mu)^2 p(x) dx$ (with a natural extension for the case when you have a probability measure not given by a density).  What's the problem?   For a normal distribution, if you can compute with the standard case then you can compute it generally.  That's computationally convenient.

It is due to the stability of the normal distribution, meaning that a linear combinations of (independent) normal random variables are normally distributed too, i.e. $$\lambda_1\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2) + \lambda_2\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2) \sim \mathcal{N}(\lambda_1\mu_1+\lambda_2\mu_2,\lambda_1^2\sigma_1^2+\lambda_2^2\sigma_2^2).$$ As a consequence, a normal distribution can be reconstructed from the standard normal law, because $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2) \sim \mu + \sigma\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, where the constant $\mu$ can be interpreted as $\mathcal{N}(\mu,0)$.

Before we tackle the standard deviation, what about the mean?  How do you define the mean of something that isn’t just a set of numbers?

Here is one way to think about this, but its not exact. Let's take the normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$. You know what this distribution looks like.
Now, let's sample from it $n$ times. What does this mean? Basically, it means that we will get numbers $x_1$, ..., $x_n$ and for each of the $x_i$, we know the probability that $x_i$ is between $a$ and $b$ is the area under the normal distribution from $a$ to $b$. So, for example, there is much higher probability that $x_i$ is between $-0.1$ and $0.1$ (right around the mean) than there is of it being between $9.9$ and $10.1$ (very far away from the mean).
Let's say $n$ is a very big number i.e. we have a very large sample. What can we expect from this sample? Well, at least three things:

If we make a histogram of the sample, it should look very similar to the original normal distribution.
The average of the sample should be very close to $0$.
The standard deviation of the sample should be very close to $1$.

If, instead, we used a normal distribution with a different mean, $\mu$, and different standard deviation, $\sigma$, then we would expect

If we make a histogram of the sample, it should look very similar to the this new normal distribution.
The average of the sample should be very close to $\mu$.
The standard deviation of the sample should be very close to $\sigma$.

Either way, the bigger the sample (i.e. the bigger $n$ is), the closer the histogram, average, and standard deviation will be to the original distribution, $\mu$, and $\sigma$.
Notice that, when you sample, you will get some big values, some small values, etc.. You'll get some $x_i$ where
$$x_i \geq \mu + 1.35 \sigma$$
and some where
$$x_i < \mu + 1.35 \sigma.$$
Using these, you can estimate things like
$$Pr(X < \mu + 1.35\sigma)$$
which, if $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$ is
$$Pr(X < 1.35).$$
One note: this is not a mathematically exact way to look at distributions. I'm just hoping it helps you get a handle on what this is saying, but as others have suggested, there are more mathematically proper ways to look at this.
